# problem in curl_setopt (Skip domain that is not available)

Tags: php, curl

There are a number of domains in the DOMAINS.json file... when one of the domains does not open (ERR_TIMED_OUT)
My script doesn't work properly and it shows the following error and it doesn't work anymore :

> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.

```
$sites = file_get_contents('./DOMAINS.json');
$sites = json_decode($sites);
function get_html_title($html){
    preg_match("/\<title.*\>(.*)\<\/title\>/isU", $html, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
function get_redirect_target($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1); 

// The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8); //timeout in seconds
    $headers = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I want it to be rejected when one of the domains has such a problem

Comment: Your script doesn't use `$sites` and never calls the functions.

Comment: If the connection fails, `$headers` will be empty. You can check for this and throw an exception, and catch this in the calling code.

Comment: @Barmar  I do not know

Comment: Can you clarify? When one of the URLs has a problem, you want to skip that domain or stop the entire loop?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `try/catch` around the loop that calls the function with each URL in the  file. Then change the function so it throws an exception when there's a failure.

```
try {
    foreach ($sites as $site) {
        get_redirect_target($site);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Unable to get redirect for $site: " . $e->getMessage();
}

function get_redirect_target($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1); 

// The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8); //timeout in seconds
    $headers = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (!$headers) {
        throw new Exception("curl error: " . curl_error($ch));
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you want to skip the bad site and continue with other sites, put the `try/catch` inside the loop, just around the call to `get_redirect_target()`.

Comment: I could not replace it properly. Is it possible to send you the script?  @Barmar

Comment: Add what you tried to the question. Leave the original code so everyone can see what the original problem was.